# Extra space beyond viewport height with certain viewport widths

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm running into an issue where I have blank space at the end of one page. As far as I can tell, there are no elements occupying the space. The space only appears when the viewport is set to certain widths. For example, it appears around width 940 and 400, but not 550 or very wide.

At first I thought it was my fixed navigation element getting in the way, but I think I've ruled that out. Any ideas what could be causing the space? It only happens on one page.

The entire site can be found here: https://github.com/NuriAmari/gina-hsu-portfolio

A demo at: https://nuriamari.github.io/gina-hsu-portfolio/

The page in question is index.html. Not sure how to more conveniently post my code, but let me know if I need to change something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew, that took some digging.

It seems that the issue was being caused from the text inside your project tiles.

Having `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Open Sans", sans-serif;` (or any font-family set) within your `*` CSS selector or any selector that affected your tiles was causing issues, as it made the text larger.

The reason was because at a certain width the text would overflow onto two lines, go crazy, and cause that extra white space.

As I assume you would want to keep the same `font-family`, you simply just need to mess with the `font-size: 5rem;` on your `body .content #projects > div a` selector. `3rem` is enough to make it compatible with everything until it hits mobile size, but of course you could use media queries to keep it whatever size you want as long as it doesn't go to two lines (because it is too large to fit within the tile size). I am sure you know, but you likely need to change/fix up the text within those tiles overall

Glad to help, let me know if you can implement that.

For future reference though, maybe give a little bit more explanation behind your question, but I was able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Alright I'll try to be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `line-height: 50vw` `css` property from `body .content #projects > div a`, will be found in `style.scss` at line `194`. Now you are good to go.

Comment: Good find, Amit. However, it's there to place the text at the bottom of each picture. Not the best solution, obviously.